# using while loop+if to make a simple game but input line not working

Tags: python, input, while-loop

after learned while loop and if, i m trying to make a super simple text game, but here is the problem: after the input line asked to type right/left, and no matter i type left or right, the code wont work. i changed the "choice" variable to left then it's working properly... I dont know what's the problems here...please tell me how to fix this to make it work.

```
choice=str(input("you are now in a forest, please pick a direction(left or right)"))
while choice == "right":
    print("a strange wind had sent you back to forest")
    choice=str(input("you are now in a forest, please pick a direction(left or right)"))
if choice == "left":
    print("u saw a cave, in or not?")
    choice= str(input("type in or not "))
    if choice == "in" :
        print("u saw a bear claw and that's the last view in your eyes")
    elif choice == "not":
        print("after two and a half hours walking, you are now out of the forest")
```

that's the code, I think the input line got some problems but I don't know what exact problems are. when I change to choice="right" or choice="left", the code is working but with this input line it's not...

Comment: Why str(input())? *input()* returns a string. Ask yourself how the code would flow if the input is anything other than what you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me; are you using all lowercase `left` or `right` with no quotes or other characters? You may want to add a `.lower().strip()` to the end of your `input` call to lowercase everything and remove leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: I want to make sure that no matter how many times people choose, the right direction will send them back to the beginning point, if people choose right twice, then the code wont evaluate anything... but thanks for the advice, i tried your idea but after i hit run button, it shows: "you are now in a forest, please pick a direction(left or right)", i typed right, then nothing happened... that's the problem i m trying to solve now...

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys I just found out why!
I have the habit to type a space between words which makes sentences clear but in this case, i type space+left/right and the while loop or if loop is looking for only "left' or "right" so I gave them a input they cannot recognize... that's stupid...
I am so sorry
thank you all for the help tho!